# Find volume of the solid which is the intersection of the solid sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9$ and the solid cylinder $x^2+y^2\leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find volume of the solid which is the intersection of the solid sphere
>   $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 9$  and the solid cylinder $x^2+y^2\leq 1$

I have used **cylindrical** **coordinates** and set up the following triple integral

$$V=2\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{9-r^2} \; r \; dz \; dr \;d \theta$$

Is this integral correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.

$$V=2\int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\color{red}{\sqrt{9-r^2}}} \; r \; dz \; dr \;d \theta$$

Comment: There is a $2$ outside.

Comment: Not sure where the $2$ came from? If its standard cylindrical coordinates shouldn't be just $r$?

Comment: If we just convert directly, the lower limit for $z$ should be $-\sqrt{9-r^2}$ but we can take advantage of symmetry and set the lower limit to $0$ and times $2$ outside.